# Very slow random write on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, freeze

I have an SSD and since I bought it I feel that it slows down in several situations, when I download a game I can't do anything because my computer freezes because it is so slow, there are games that keep freezing and that don't work this was supposed to happen. In the game Hogwarts Legacy, there are times when the floor doesn't load and I fall into infinity or simply before I attack the enemies I freeze, although the game runs perfectly.

I have a Ryzen 5 3600 / RX 6600 / 16GB DDR4 3200Mhz / Motherboard BIOSTAR B350GTX .

My SSD is a Crucial CT960 BX500.

Benchmark CrystalDiskMark:
[image: Benchmark CrystalDiskMark]

CrystalDiskInfo:
[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Every game I download on Steam starts downloading and after a few seconds it stops and comes back and stays in this loop until it finishes downloading, meanwhile my computer is extremely slow and I can't do anything, I have fiber optic internet.

Steam Stop Donwloading:
[image: Steam Stop Donwloading]

- I have already activated TRIM.
- I have already disabled the hard drive's sleep mode in the power
  options.
- EDIT 1 - Cache in devige manage was already enabled

Comment: `there are times when the floor doesn't load and I fall into infinity or simply before I attack the enemies I freeze, although the game runs perfectly`  makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Check the corresponding item under `Disk drives` in `Device Manager`. Maybe the drive's write cache has been disabled.

Comment: Btw try to toggle (uncheck->ok->check->ok) the checkbox even if it's checked and see if it makes any difference: https://www.howto-connect.com/enable-or-disable-disk-write-caching-in-windows-8/

Comment: How much free space available on the SSD? You can try go into BIOS and just let it sit there for few hours so it can do garbage collect etc..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The game runs at 60 fps at all times on the high setting, but every 1 hour or so the problem that I said about the floor not loading happens, my English is bad, sorry

Comment: @TomYan Cache in devige manage was already enabled :c

Comment: You are focusing a lot on the SSD, but did you make sure the PC is doing fine otherwise? Like no excessive CPU load when it should be (relatively) idle and so on. Are you using special virus scanner or other security software?

Comment: Maybe see if there's any available firmware update. May consider switching AHCI controller driver (Windows builtin vs AMD provided, whichever you are not using now) as well (although it might break booting).

Comment: Your English is PERFECT.  Don't worry about that.  We are all just trying to help you with your problem.  We don't care about English skills as long as we can understand the question.